# Sql query to not return the user who has a particular value in an column of a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rdbms

So I am facing some problem with this sql query(MYSQL) where I do not want to return the user record if one of the columns in another table contains a certain value.

This the structure of the tables:

[image: Person Table]

[image: Person Attribute Table]

[image: Person Attribute Type Table]

Description of the tables:

1. The person table is self explanatory. It just contains various info regarding the person that I am returning
2. The Person Attribute table describes the attributes a person may have along with its values and its type where person_attribute_type_id is a foreign key
3. The Person Attribute Type describes the different attributes types.

Now I have a person_attribute_type called `PATIENT_STATE` i.e. there is a record with `name` column in person_attribute_type table with value `PATIENT_STATE`

I do not want to return any persons, who have have a Person Attribute of type `PATIENT_STATE`, but all others.

The following is the sql query that I have written:

```
    select 
       p.uuid as uuid, pat.value as Atribute, p.person_id as personId,
       p.gender as gender, p.birthdate as birthDate, p.death_date as 
       deathDate, p.birthdate_estimated as birthdateEstimated,
       p.date_created as dateCreated
    from person p 

       left join person_name pn on pn.person_id = p.person_id
       JOIN person_attribute pat on p.person_id=pat.person_id and 
       pat.voided = 'false' and pat.person_attribute_type_id NOT IN 
        (SELECT person_attribute_type_id from person_attribute_type 
        where name='PATIENT_STATE') 
    where p.voided = 'false' and pn.voided = 'false' and ( 
    concat_ws(' ',coalesce(given_name), coalesce(middle_name), 
    coalesce(family_name)) like  '%Aud%') group by  p.person_id;
```

In the sql query `%Aud%` is like my search query

If I run the above query, it does not return the record for which the person had `PATIENT_STATE` but it returns a record where say the Person Attribute is `XXX`. The thing is that I want to check if the person contains `PATIENT_STATE` as his attribute. If there is, I do not want to return that person's record even if it contains any other attribute types.

How do I go about this?

Comment: We lurrrve data. We hate pictures of data. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want to return any persons, who have have a Person Attribute of type PATIENT_STATE, but all others.

From what you describe, this sounds like a `not exists` query:

```
select p.*
from person p
where not exists (select 1
                  from person_attribute pa join
                       person_attribute_type pat
                       on pat.person_attribute_type_id = pa.person_attribute_type_id
                  where pat.name = 'PATIENT_STATE' and
                        pa.person_id = p.person_id
                 );
```

You can also express this as `left join`s if you want:

```
select p.*
from person p left join
     person_attribute pa
     on pa.person_id = p.person_id left join
     person_attribute_type pat
     on pat.person_attribute_type_id = pa.person_attribute_type_id and
        pat.name = 'PATIENT_STATE' 
where pat.person_attribute_type_id is null;
```

You query is returning a value from `person_attribute_type`.  I don't think that makes sense, given that your question is for an attribute that is missing.

Comment: The pat.value Im returning is just for representational purposes. Also I have named my person_attribute as `pat` and not `pa`. I guess that was your query. Will try out your query and let you know. Thanks a lot!!!